# How can i bind my website with sub domain name.in IIS?

Tags: c#, angular, iis, devops

What is happening currently ?
https://example.com/ ---> binded to my app.

What is expected ?
https://example.com/path1 ---> binded to my app.

when i try to do it gives me error that i cannot add (.,:,/) etc.

Comment: It's not subdomain. It's subfolder. You can not bind subfolder. Bind path1.example.com to your site. Binding happens to HOST, not to folder or path.

Comment: you are correct but we are using GD authentication and our GD server binded to that "www.example.com" and GD team given this path where redirection will happen. So i have to bind "example/sub1".

Comment: Show things like the actual error page. It is impolite to ask others to guess.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind example.com to a site in IIS all request with this domain (without considering the consecutive parts) are binded too (example.com/*).
There are two solutions here:

1. Using url rewrite module and redirect users with the path of example.com to another place (for example to a not authorize page) and only accept those with the path of example.com/path1
2. Using HAProxy or another web server in front of you IIS that can proxy users with example.com/path1 to your IIS website and redirect users with the path of example.com to another place.